# OpenAM Register Remote Service Provider using SSOADM

Tags: openam

For the purposes of fully automating an OpenAM deployment, can we Register a Remote Service Provider using SSOADM Command Line Interface or any other tool?

I don't see this option in the [list of arguments](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/reference/index/ssoadm-1.html) for ssoadm.  Is there a way to do this with ssoadm or perhaps another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the Federation Management section in the documentation. The command you are looking for is "[import-entity](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/reference/index/ssoadm-1.html#ssoadm-import-entity)".